# What is the easiest way to generate a clock signal?

Tags: oscillator, clock, dac, crystal

I'm pretty much a beginner with electronics, and I am currently making an audio circuit, using the TI PCM1755 24-bit DAC. For my application, the IC needs a 49152 kHz clock to its SCK pin. Is there a way to do this, if possible with very little passives?

The ESP32-C3 that is also part of my design needs a crystal oscillator, but the reference design included a schematic that i just copied and adjusted for my crystal. It also had two pins, so I can't use it again, right?

Thanks in advance, Laurin

[PCM175x series datasheet](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=26&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fpcm1755).

Comment: You can simply purchase an oscillator module with the required frequency. The esp32 may be able to generate that frequency as well. There are plenty of audio dac designs on the interwebs - how do they solve the problem? How is your problem different?

Comment: I don't believe ESP32 can generate 49.152 MHz. Furthermore ESP32 has silicon issues regarding I2S in slave mode (if you use an external oscillator). Search the Espressif forums for I2S slave bugs. If at all possible stick to master mode and a slower clock (I have good results with 12.888 MHz which is enough for 16 bit 48 kHz stereo).

Comment: Eventually, use a synthesiser ...  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9850.pdf  there is some boards with it or same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DAC does not just need **a** clock, the clock must be **the** audio system clock from which all the other clocks (bit clock and frame clock) are derived from. If you don't have this, you must generate a synchronous system clock with a PLL from the bit clock.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look that up, thanks for the quick help.

Comment: @Laurin Also please note that the only case you need a 49.152 MHz system clock is when using 96 kHz rate with 512xFs system clock. Which is very rare as it would work with lower system clock just fine.